# Use tidyverse filter to keep values in a column based on another

Tags: r, filter, tidyverse

I have a dataframe df1 where one column is ID and another column is PAN (for pandemic), values are either yes or no, for whether the observation was during or before the pandemic.

I want to only keep IDs that have both a before and during, or a yes AND a no in the PAN column.

I can filter to keep only yeses or only nos, I don't know how to keep IDs that have both. They will be separate rows.

so

```
df1 <-  read.table(text = "ID PAN
                         1   NO
                         1   YES
                         2  YES
                         2   NO
                         3  NO
                         4   YES
                         5   NO
                         5   YES",
                           header = TRUE)
```

How do I only keep IDs 1, 2 and 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr` you can use

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  filter(any(PAN=="YES") & any(PAN=="NO"), .by=ID)

#   ID PAN
# 1  1  NO
# 2  1 YES
# 3  2 YES
# 4  2  NO
# 5  5  NO
# 6  5 YES
```

The filter checks that there is a YES and NO value somewhere within each group.

Answer (score 0):

Another one-liner. This filters groups with number of distinct element > 1. You could use `n_distinct(PAN)==2` as well.

```
library(dplyr)
df1%>%
  filter(n_distinct(PAN)>1,.by=ID)

  ID PAN
1  1  NO
2  1 YES
3  2 YES
4  2  NO
5  5  NO
6  5 YES
```

Answer (score 0):

We can test if `all` of "YES" and "NO" are found `in` `PAN`.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 |>
    filter(all(c("YES", "NO") %in% PAN), .by = ID)
```